# Changing Activities with toolbar items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

Sorry for my english :)

I have an item in the toolbar and when the user clicks on the item I would like it to go back to previous activity or go to any other activities that I choose.

Thanks for help

actually this is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.back)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(listActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Can yo post some code? showing your toolbar/activity item?

Comment: if you wanna get to activity behind this activity you may want to finish this activity in onMenuItemClick and if you wanna get to another activity you have to start it with an intent

Comment: "it comes back to before activity or in any activities that I choose" what does this mean? User clicks items, he/she is navigated to new activity, now what ? You want to force them to go back to listactivity?

Comment: @Hossein what is the problem with your code ?

Comment: @Mahfa The code is ok  and i have no errors but it dose't work

Comment: @Hossein see here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html you have to handle the clicks of android.R.id.home

Comment: If you want it to go back to the previous activity, call `onBackPressed()` instead of creating a new intent and lauching it.

Comment: thanks dear friend @Talha

Comment: thanks dear @Mahfa U help me a lot

Comment: thank u dear @RafaelCardoso

Comment: @Hossein Ur welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your toolbar home button property,

```
toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Try calling finish() method.

```
if(id==android.R.id.home)
  {
  this.finish();
  return true;
  }
```

As @Mahfa already said, calling finish() will always navigate you back where you came from, in your case, MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

In fact all of this answers really helped me in someways

but the exact code that worked for me is like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Accept as answer if this solved your problem. Thanks.